# How can I make a modal like in the picture - discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

I want to create a modal like in the picture when the button is pressed. How can I make this model with Discord.py or nextcord?

[image]

Comment: Modal is not available in Nextcord currently. You can try to use [pycord](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=modal#discord.ui.Modal)

Comment: Modal will be available in nextcord v2.0.0a10

Answer (score 6):

You can find examples for modals in Nextcord here:

https://github.com/nextcord/nextcord/blob/master/examples/modals/

```py
class Pet(nextcord.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Your pet")  # Modal title

        # Create a text input and add it to the modal
        self.name = nextcord.ui.TextInput(
            label="Your pet's name",
            min_length=2,
            max_length=50,
        )
        self.add_item(self.name)

        # Create a long text input and add it to the modal
        self.description = nextcord.ui.TextInput(
            label="Description",
            style=nextcord.TextInputStyle.paragraph,
            placeholder="Information that can help us recognise your pet",
            required=False,
            max_length=1800,
        )
        self.add_item(self.description)

    async def callback(self, interaction: nextcord.Interaction) -> None:
        """This is the function that gets called when the submit button is pressed"""
        response = f"{interaction.user.mention}'s favourite pet's name is {self.name.value}."
        if self.description.value != "":
            response += f"\nTheir pet can be recognized by this information:\n{self.description.value}"
        await interaction.send(response)

@bot.slash_command(
    name="pet",
    description="Describe your favourite pet",
    guild_ids=[TESTING_GUILD_ID],
)
async def send(interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
    # sending the modal on an interaction (can be slash, buttons, or select menus)
    modal = Pet()
    await interaction.response.send_modal(modal)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Modal(ui.Modal, title="test title"):
    firstfield = ui.TextInput(label="firstfield",placeholder="write here", style=discord.TextStyle.short)
    secondfield = ui.TextInput(label="secondfield",placeholder="write here", style=discord.TextStyle.short)
    thirdfield = ui.TextInput(label="thirdfield:",placeholder="write here", style=discord.TextStyle.short)
    first_big_field = ui.TextInput(label="first_big_field:",placeholder="write here", style=discord.TextStyle.long)
    second_big_field = ui.TextInput(label="second_big_field:",placeholder="write here", style=discord.TextStyle.long)
```

Then u can call `Modal()` where u want